# How to remove root element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Sorry for the simple question, but I cannot find an answer...

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Test[] {new Test() {X = 1}, new Test() {X = 2}};
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test[]));
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, x);
    } 
}

public class Test
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

Returns

```
<ArrayOfTest>
  <Test>
    <X>1</X>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <X>2</X>
  </Test>
</ArrayOfTest>
```

How can I remove `<ArrayOfTest>`? I found only how to rename the root element. And how to remove in case when `Test[]` inside another class (we can use `[XmlElement("Test")]` then).

Comment: You will not have a proper xml file.  The root level of an xml cannot have an array.

Comment: I need to paste this code to another place

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create another class that wraps your `Test` class:

```
[XmlRoot("Tests")]
public class Tests: List<Test>
{
}
```

The outer element will now be named "Tests".

Now use your serializer with the new wrapper class:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tests));
```

**EDIT:** Another option if you want to remove one level of tags, but I'm not sure if it is more clear (but maybe it fits your needs better):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Tests { 1, 2, 3 };
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tests));
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, x);
    }        
}

[XmlRoot("Tests")]
public class Tests : List<int>
{
}
```

Output:

```
<Tests>
    <int>1</int>
    <int>2</int>
</Tests>
```

Comment: will it remove the root element ??

Comment: No... I got <Tests> instead <ArrayOf>

Comment: exactly the author wants to remove tag not renaming it! @Jurjen

Comment: @Serg046 well, first of all you will always need root elements otherwise your XML is not valid. You could probably remove one element, but that does not make it nicer imho. I'm not sure if there is an elegant way around it. I feel it will only make your XML less readable though. See my edit, maybe that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a proper format, but just the information itself with the **Test** objects, write it to a MemoryStream (System.IO) and cut off the first and last line afterwards.

```
var x = new Test[] { new Test() { X = 1 }, new Test() { X = 2 } };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test[]));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(ms, x);
ms.Position = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));
string xmlSerializedObject = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length)));`
```

Comment: It's not the most beautiful, but a string is easy to manipulate.

Comment: To get the string value I can use StringWriter() instead of MemoryStream. But I'm looking for another way.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know.